# Bootstrap Thumbnails Leave gaps in between

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a grid of Boostrap unevenly sized thumbnails. But some thumbnails are uneven, resulting in huge gaps between some rows. 
[image: picture of thumbnails gaps]

I don't have any styling on the thumbnails.

Is there a way to fix it without adding something like Masonry/Isotope/Salvattore?

Comment: Can you post (edit your question) the code you are using for your approach?

Comment: maybe an div with style  "clear:both" between each row, but it still look terrible because the different height of each thumb, so i suggest use some technique to make your thumb same height (you can search the site for this, alot of solutions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cleanest way to fix  your layout is to use a masonry type of layout. It will allow for the smoothest look and be a very fluid and responsive layout when dealing with mixed sized media. Though if you are in complete control of the data/images being placed on the site I would suggest creating each image to be identical in size and type. If you would like I can provide an example I have created using a masonry type of layout with thumbnails and Bootstrap.

Edit to add example code:

```
/* CSS styles */
.row {
    -moz-column-width: 12em;
    -webkit-column-width: 12em;
    -moz-column-gap: 1em;
    -webkit-column-gap:1em;  
    column-width: 12em;
    column-gap: 1em;
    column-fill: balance;
    width: 100%;
}

/* Outer div block */
.section-block {
    display: block;
    padding:  .25rem;
    width:  100%; 
}

/* Inner div block */
.section-item {
   position:relative;
   display: inline-block;
   width: 100%;
}

.section-item img{
    width: 100%;
}

//Wrapper for each img you are adding
<div class='section-block'>
    <div class='section-item'>
        <div>
            <a href='#' class='thumbnail' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#id'>
                <img src='/imgs/image.jpg'>
                <p class='caption'>Image Caption</p>
            </a>                            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I used this in conjunction with php to get all my images from a db then I looped over each image and echo'd to the page with the above syntax. This should work without having to use any additional js libraries beyond what you are using for bootstrap. This gives you a very responsive masonry style of layout that works in modern browsers.

Answer (score 2):

You can use two `<div>` or two `.row` tags like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="..." alt="...">
      <div class="caption">
        <p>Thumbnail caption</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="..." alt="...">
      <div class="caption">
        <p>Thumbnail caption</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="..." alt="...">
      <div class="caption">
        <p>Thumbnail caption</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="..." alt="...">
      <div class="caption">
        <p>Thumbnail caption</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="..." alt="...">
      <div class="caption">
        <p>Thumbnail caption</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="..." alt="...">
      <div class="caption">
        <p>Thumbnail caption</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For more info visit [Example: Stacked-to-horizontal](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic).